# How can I reset the controls from UserControl when BringToFront()?

Tags: c#, winforms

I designed a hamburgermenu winforms application, lets say I have "button 1" & "button 2" , when the user clicks the "button 1" the "UserControl1" will show using .BringToFront() , and when the user clicks the "button 2" the "UserControl2" will show , so when I click the the "button 1" again , I want my controls from my "UserControl1" will reset, example I have textbox's on the "serControl1" I want its  "text value" to be empty again, how is that?

Thanks,
NicoTing

Comment: You can add a public `Reset` method to the user control. A better idea would be creating a new instance of the control and replacing the old one with the new one, then dispose the old one. And as a much better idea, you can use a model as data source of the control and by passing a new clean model instance, the user control will be reset.

Comment: Surely on clicking button 2 you can just reset it.

Comment: can u guys please provide a code? Thanks

Comment: You can use Show and Hide instead of the z-order. (Somewhat cleaner anyway, imo!) Then you can code the VisibleChanged events..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either of the following:

- Creating a public `Reset` method for your control to reset values for the controls.
- You can create `Model` or `DataSource` property for your control and use data-binding. So resetting would be passing a new instance of model to the `Model` property of the control.

**Example - Public Reset Method**

In your `UserControl`, you can create a public `Reset` method which reset controls. Then you can simply call `userControl.Reset()` whenever you need:

```
public void Reset()
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
    checkBox1.Checked = false;
    // and so on ...
}
```

Comment: oh yes this is what I did yesterday, I miss something thats why its not working lol , thanks btw

Comment: Great! You're welcome.